# Streaming objects from S3 Object using Spring Aws Integration

Tags: amazon-s3, streaming, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am working on a usecase where I am supposed to poll S3 -> read the stream for the content -> do some processing and upload it to another bucket rather than writing the file in my server.

I know I can achieve it using S3StreamingMessageSource in Spring aws integration but the problem I am facing is that I do not know on how to process the message stream received by polling

```
public class S3PollerConfigurationUsingStreaming {
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.newBucket}")
    private String newBucket;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonClientService amazonClient;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3Channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> s3InboundStreamingMessageSource() {    
        S3StreamingMessageSource messageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(template());
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(bucketName);
        messageSource.setFilter(new S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
                "streaming"));      
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "s3Channel", outputChannel = "data")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
        return new StreamTransformer();
    }

    @Bean
    public S3RemoteFileTemplate template() {
        return new S3RemoteFileTemplate(new S3SessionFactory(amazonClient.getS3Client()));
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel s3Channel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow fileStreamingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(streamFile())
                .get();
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me with the code to process the stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is your problem, but I see that you have a mix of concerns. If you use messaging annotations (see `@InboundChannelAdapter` in your config), what is the point to use the same `s3InboundStreamingMessageSource` in the `IntegrationFlow` definition?

Anyway it looks like you have already explored for yourself a `StreamTransformer`. This one has a `charset` property to convert your `InputStream`from the remote S3 resource to the `String`. Otherwise it returns a `byte[]`. Everything else is up to you what and how to do with this converted content.

Also I don't see reason to have an `s3Channel` as a `QueueChannel`, since the start of your flow is pollable anyway by the `@InboundChannelAdapter`.

From big height I would say we have more questions to you, than vise versa...

**UPDATE**

Not clear what is your idea for `InputStream` processing, but that is really a fact that after `S3StreamingMessageSource` you are going to have exactly `InputStream` as a payload in the next handler.

Also not sure what is your `streamFile()`, but it must really expect `InputStream` as an input from the payload of the request message. 
You also can use the mentioned `StreamTransformer` over there:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow fileStreamingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .transform(Transformers.fromStream("UTF-8"))
            .get();
}
```

And the next `.handle()` will be ready for `String` as a payload.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the concerns with the code. My exact question is how do i get the input stream from remote S3 resource in the streamFile() method so that I can process it ? I am new to spring-integration that's why I am not getting the hang of it

Comment: I know I will have to get the file from payload like below MessageSource<InputStream> msgSource;
msgSource.receive().getPayload() . My doubt is from where do I get the msgSource ? I know it might sound naive but I very new to spring-integration

Comment: I don't know how to explain your simple way, but you don't call `msgSource.receive()` yourself. The `@InboundChannelAdapter` or `ntegrationFlows.from()` with the poller does the trick to poll that `MessageSource` and produce messages for the configured channel with the `InputStream` as a payload for each remote file.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: how to i access that message in processFile() method in ' IntegrationFlows
            .from(s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .transform(Transformers.fromStream("UTF-8"))
            .handle(processFile()).get() '  so that i can access the file's inputstream from the payload ?

Comment: First of all the code is not readable in the comment. Second, if you need exactly `InputStream`, you don't need that transformer at all, but just expect `InputStream` in the arguments of your `processFile()`. There is just no `File` in case of `s3InboundStreamingMessageSource`. Please, read more in the reference manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming. You need to understand that `s3InboundStreamingMessageSource` produces messages exactly with the `InputStream` payloads and that is what you need exact in your POJO method for the `handle()`

Comment: Hi Artem. I am facing connection exhaustion while polling object from S3 using S3StreamingMessageSource. Here's the SO link for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056264/timeout-waiting-for-connection-from-pool-while-polling-s3-for-objects. It would be great if you can take a look at it if possible. I am desperately seeking help as I don't have much help and resources for this online