# Timeout waiting for connection from pool while polling S3 for Objects

Tags: java, amazon-s3, streaming, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am working on a backend service which polls S3 bucket periodically using spring aws integration and processes the polled object from S3. Below is the implementation for it

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class S3PollerConfiguration {

    //private static final Logger log = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3PollerConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> s3InboundStreamingMessageSource() {    
        S3StreamingMessageSource messageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(template());
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(bucketName);   
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public S3RemoteFileTemplate template() {
        return new S3RemoteFileTemplate(new S3SessionFactory(thumbnailGeneratorService.getImagesS3Client()));
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() throws IOException {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(Message.class, (payload, header) -> processS3Object(payload.getHeaders(), payload.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }
}
```

I am getting the messages from S3 on object upload and I am able to process it using the input stream received as part of message payload. But the problem I face here is that I get 'Time out waiting for connection from pool' exception after receiving few messages

```
2019-01-06 02:19:06.156 ERROR 11322 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.list(RemoteFileTemplate.java:405)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.listFiles(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:194)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.poll(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.S3StreamingMessageSource.poll(S3StreamingMessageSource.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:250)
```

I know that the issue is related to not closing the opened S3Object like stated here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405 so I have implemented closing the input stream of the S3Object received as part of message payload. But that does not solve the issue and I keep getting the exceptions. Can someone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: can you share how do you exactly close those streams?

Comment: public MessageHandler processS3Object(MessageHeaders headers, Object obj) { InputStream is = (InputStream) obj; // Do processing with is ;                               
   is.close(); }

Comment: @slimane : Thanks for intending to help. I am just closing the input stream after processing the stream. I think i need to close the S3Object but do not know how to get access to it as part of the streaming message

Comment: try to remove @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5")) from s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(), as you will have two definition for the same bean in your context

Comment: @slimane : Is that the cause of the issue ?

Comment: Please, see my answer with detailed explanation what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you still mix Messaging Annotations declarations with Java DSL in your configuration.

Looks like in the `fileReadingFlow` you close those `InputStream`s in your code `processS3Object()` method, but you do nothing with `InputStream`s produced by the `@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5"))`.
Why do you have it in fist place at all? What makes you to keep that code if you don't use it?

This `S3StreamingMessageSource` is polled all the time twice: by the `@InboundChannelAdapter` and `IntegrationFlows.from()`.

You just have to remove that `@InboundChannelAdapter` from the `S3StreamingMessageSource` bean definition and that's all.

Please, read more Reference Manual to determine the reason of such an annotation and how you don't need it when you use Java DSL:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#_using_the_literal_inboundchanneladapter_literal_annotation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-inbound-adapters